# How do I list more than 50 Youtube videos in a channel using nextPageToken?

Tags: youtube, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Using the following link, it listed all of my videos up to 50 results.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={your_key_here}&channelId={channel_id_here}&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=50
```

However, I wanted to list all of my videos in my channel so I added in the `pageToken` parameter (max 500 results). Here is the link I used by adding this in `pageToken=nextPageToken`

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={your_key_here}&channelId={channel_id_here}&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=50&pageToken=nextPageToken
```

However, it gave me the following error

```
{
     "error": {
          "errors": [
           {
                "domain": "youtube.parameter",
                "reason": "invalidPageToken",
                "message": "The request specifies an invalid page token.",
                "locationType": "parameter",
                "location": "pageToken"
           }
          ],
          "code": 400,
          "message": "The request specifies an invalid page token."
     }
}
```

How is this supposed to be replicated so it will actually display the `nextPageToken`?

Answer (score 3):

When you do a search, the results contain a `nextPageToken` field if there is another page of results.

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"cbz3lIQ2N25AfwNr-BdxUVxJ_QY/jtd94kasKWBOdCB882K5N-sSrnQ\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CAEQAA",
 "regionCode": "US",
 "pageInfo": {
 "totalResults": 1000000,
 "resultsPerPage": 1
},
```

Setting `pageToken` in your next search call equal to that `nextPageToken` value will return the next page.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?...&pageToken=CAEQAA
```